# gem version conflict installing resque 1.18 in Rails 2.3.8

Tags: rubygems, resque, ruby-on-rails-2, versions

I installed redis and resque in Rails 2.3.8 by gem install redis and gem install resque. The version of resque and redis are 1.18.0 and 2.2.2 respectively. I started the worker by

```
RAILS_ENV=development resque-web config/initializers/resque.rb
```

I also did the configurations in the config/redis.yml file as:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  ...
```

and `config/initializers/resque.rb` as:

```
config = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/redis.yml"))[Rails.env]
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => config['host'], :port => config['port'])
```

But when I want to start the resque-web by

```
RAILS_ENV=development resque-web config/initializers/resque.rb
```

I get this error

> ./config/initializers/../../vendors/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:27:in
>   'require_frameworks' : can't activate rack (~> 1.1.0, runtime) for [],
>   already activated rack-1.4.1 for ["vegas-0.1.11", "resque-1.18.0"]

I found out that `resque 1.18.0` requires `sinatra 1.3.3` as it dependency which again requires `rack >= 1.3.0` as its dependency. However, for `actionpack` for `rails 2.3.8`, the version for `rack` wanted is `1.1.0`. Can anyone please suggest me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a version of `resque` which requires a lower version of `sinatra` which then requires a version of `rack` that is compatible with `rails 2.3.8`.

You can figure this out manually, or try one of these options:

1. Use the RubyGems dependency API (http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-org-api/)
2. Retrofit `bundler` in your Rails 2.3.8 application